# Which is the correct syntax in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this function called `destroy_order_payment_detail` and I'm trying to destroy a dependent object. It's not working, so which of these syntaxes are correct?

```
has_one :order_payment_detail, inverse_of: :payment_order
accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_payment_detail, allow_destroy: true

before_destroy :destroy_order_payment_detail

private
    def destroy_order_payment_detail
      if :order_payment_detail.present?
        :order_payment_detail.destroy
      end
    end
```

or this one without the `:`?

```
private
    def destroy_order_payment_detail
      if order_payment_detail.present?
        order_payment_detail.destroy
      end
    end
```

Comment: The second one without the colon `:`, why are you adding the `:` btw?

Comment: I added the colon just to test if it would work

Comment: If i use this approach in the controller.rb instead, it would be better?
`@payment_order.order_payment_detail.destroy`

Comment: Define "it's not working". Regarding adding the `:` -- would it make sense to call `.present?` on a symbol when you're wondering about the content of `order_payment_detail`?

Comment: I used `.present?` to see if the `payment_order` has a `order_payment_detail`, but i dont know if there is a better way to do so. I'm new in ruby.

Comment: I'm not asking why call `#present?`, I'm asking you to consider what it's being called **on**. In other words: what does `present?` mean for a symbol vs a reference. This answers your question regarding which is correct *(in this situation)*.

Comment: _It's not working_ — what does it mean? Do you have some errors?

Comment: It returns status 500, but no errors message

Answer (score 3):

If you're wanting to destroy the dependent order_payment_detail, there's a better way than to write a callback, simply declare the dependency like this:

```rb
has_one :order_payment_detail, inverse_of: :payment_order, dependent: :destroy
```

no need for the `before_destroy` callback

Comment: Do i need to write something in the parent destroy method?

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: you need to be clearer about "it doesn't work". In other comments you mention 500 error. Is that what you're seeing? Look in the development.log file and find out what's happening when it "doesn't work". What is the name of the model that "has_one :order_payment_detail"?

Comment: In which folder the development,log file is ? The model is called `payment_order.rb`

Comment: This is the error im receiving : `NameError (uninitialized constant PaymentOrder::OrderPaymentDetail):`

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong in my case, when i tried to destroy the order_payment_detail ruby would look for a model named order_payment_detail.rb. But the name of the model was payment_order_detail, so i only needed to rename the dependent and now it destroys as it is supposed to do.
Sorry for taking your time.